Name for difficulty to put together meaning of a text?
Is there any known symptom where one has difficulties grasping the meaning of a sentence “son of mother’s brother“ in a context like “He is my close relative, namely the son of mother’s brother”?
For example, the person says that he can’t make sense of this sentence in free speech conversation, and asks for a pause for thinking. After some time, when suggested to write down the sentence, he says that despite that now it becomes easier to get it together, it is still hard. Only after drawing arrows on air, he gets the point.
As far as I know, the majority of people don’t have any issues with the sentence, and grasp it at once without any visible effort. It sounds to me like a difficulty to put together meaning of a text - getting bigger picture from separate words.
Is there a name for this symptom that I could use to find more to read on the subject?
Why it is hard to find the answer in books
When I address this topic to classical research, they mostly cover two issues here:

For speech they address sound processing related problems like segmentation problem or invariance problem.
For text perception they address lack of nonverbal cues.

Both are not the case here, since they are sound- or text- specific and in the described case the problem lies in a different area; let's say "perception" or "generalization" when a person compiles more general terms from words.
